# MVC4 -> HttpHandler that redirects to a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, httphandler

I have a web app ( all HTML/Jquery ), which I want to distribute to subscribers via the URL MySite/SubscriberId, without having endless copies of my code.  So I have made a HTTP handler, which looks like this:

```
        var routeValues = requestContext.RouteData.Values;

        if (routeValues.ContainsKey("name"))
        {
            string name = routeValues["name"].ToString();


            switch(GetUserType(name))
            {
                case UserType.Invalid:
                    break;
                case UserType.Developer:
                    redirect = Settings.BetaAppPath;
                    break;
                case UserType.Standard:
                    redirect = Settings.FullAppPath;
                    break;
                case UserType.Tester:
                    redirect = Settings.TesterAppPath;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

This returns strings like /Code/Full or /Code/Beta.  These folders exist and are part of my solution.  The only way I've found to redirect at this point, is something like this:

```
        var page = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(redirect, typeof(Page)) as IHttpHandler;

        return page;
```

which, I believe, actually executes the page in the URL and returns the HTML.  However, there is no page here, it's the root folder of a ton of files I want downloaded to the client.  I tried doing a Server.Transfer, but this works, but it changes the client side URL.  I am using the client name on the URL to log the user in, in the application, so this does not work for me.  I need the URL in the browser not to change, but the URL myURL/username to return the contents of myURL/Code/Full.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try

```
return RedirectToLocal(url);
```

From an HttpHandler you should be able to do something like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not in a controller, I am in a HTTPHandler.  I was considering just registering all my user names as urls in my route registry, is that what you're suggesting, and have a controller that redirects to my actual local code base ? Would that change the URL the client sees ? That is my showstopper.

Comment: No, it's pretty much what I had already done.  The issue is, the URL in the browser becomes /Code/Full and I need for it not to change.  Thanks for trying to help, but, that's where I started.  I need to do exactly what this code is doing, without the URL changing in the browser, and I need to direct to a folder, not to a single file.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to create a controller instead of a HttpHandler? I mean for doing the redirect, not the pages themselves.

Comment: I am rewriting an existing site, where the format is sitename/username.  I would have to register controllers for each username with a default page, to keep using the existing format ( which has users ).  A HTTPHandler that catches the URL ( which we currently create and have endless copies of our app ), seems the logical path to me, but if you have a better idea, I'm all ears :-)  I cannot change the URL format, that is the thing.